# Why is the compiler Error CS0116 above everything?

Tags: c#

I get [Compiler Error CS0116](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xx071h86%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) in the code:

```
<%@ Page EnableEventValidation="false" ValidateRequest="false" Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"

CodeFile="../Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="x.Program" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="Validators" Namespace="Sample.Web.UI.Compatibility" TagPrefix="cc1" %>

<%@ Import Namespace="System.IO" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<title>Title</title>
<link href="StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body class="mainbody"></body>
</html>
```

script code in Default.aspx.cs(Please note that "this random text somehow ignored" is ignored and no syntax error is generated):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

//this random text somehow ignored (now commented)

namespace x
{
// To fix the error, you must
// enclose a method in a class:

 class Program // changed from Class Program
 {
 void Method2(string str)
  {
  Console.WriteLine(str)
  }
 }
}
```

Why is the compiler Error CS0116 appearing? Why are the other things ignored (such as syntax error)? Update: Please note, if I delete "this random text somehow ignored" line error still persist.

FINAL UPDATE:
Solution is 
1. Obviously, extra line should be deleted.
2. Tools->Options->Text Editor->Basic->VB-Specific->Pretty listing(reformatting) of code was on and caused automatic change of case ("class" to "Class"). I didn't notice it straight away.
Thank you very much. It works as charm now. @Rob Levine and @Guffa I can accept only one answer, but you both did a great job!

Comment: Your question contains it's own answer in several places (the error message, the comment, and indirectly your remark on 'somehow ignored'). It is a poor question for that reason, and for omitting the compiler error message in the first place

Comment: Please note if I delete "this random text somehow ignored" line error still persist. No for you I will repeat: That line DOES NOT matter. Ignore it if you wish. The line was added deliberately to emphasize the fact that syntax error is somehow ignored. All in all my question does not contain it's own answer. So it is reasonable question to ask.

Comment: According to your own comments to the existing answers, the code you posted above is no longer current. Make sure you apply both suggestions and then edit your question with the updated code, assuming the error is still there.

Comment: Also, just because deleting a single line doesn't make the error go away, that doesn't mean it can be ignored. It just means you have multiple errors in your code.

Comment: have you tried both my answer and Guffa's answer *at the same time*? They are both causing the same problem to the compiler. They are both unrecognised stuff (that looks like a declaration of some sort) directly in the namespace and not enclosed in a class (or struct). Either one of them will cause the error you are seeing. You have to correct them both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error CS0116 is appearing precisely because of your line

```
this random text somehow ignored
```

This error message appears to tell you that members such as fields, methods, properties, etc, cannot appear directly inside the namespace - they need to be enclosed in a class or struct. [As Marc points out in the comment - even though this line appears above the namespace declaration, it is still considered to be directly inside the *global* namespace]

In other words - because it sees this compile issue, it doesn't bother attempting to make any further sense of what you may have in the class file, and doesn't give you any syntax error type messages - it is really saying "this file is totally wrong and I'm not even going to try and make sense of it."

Comment: it is worth noting (for the OP) that this is in the root / global namespace - but that the same rules still apply. It is still a namespace.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. If I delete "this random text somehow ignored" line error still persist. So the problem is not there.

Comment: That is because you *also* have the issue Guffa notes in his answer - you need to change the capitalization on "Class" to "class". As far as the compiler is concerned these are both the same problem: unrecognised stuff that looks like a declaration of some sort, which is directly in the namespace and not in a class (or struct)

Answer (score 3):

Change `Class` to `class`.

> C# is case sensetive.

As the compiler doesn't recognise `Class`,
the method is still not in a class, and you still get the same error.

Comment: @Marc Gravell: As the class is added to fix that specific error, I think that it's actually the spelling that is the main problem.

Comment: @Pavel Nefyodov: Now you should only get that error once, from the random text that you added, and no longer from the class. You also get an error from the missing semicolon on the line in the method. You don't get a syntax error from the random text, because it's close enough to real code that the CS0116 error kicks in first.

Comment: @Pavel - have you tried both Guffa's answer and mine at the same time? They are both giving rise to the same problem - unexpected stuff (that looks to the compiler like a declaration of some sort) directly in the namespace.